# selenium cssSelctor with the use of class and text

Tags: class, text, selenium-webdriver, anchor

How to create cssSelctor with the use of class and the text "Financial Modules", please check the screen attached.

I tried given but not working:

[image]

- `findElement(By.cssSelector("a[text='Financial Modules']")).click();`
- `findElement(By.cssSelector("a:contains('Financial Modules')")).click();`
- `findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='ui-tabs-anchor'][text='Financial Modules']")).click();`
- `findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-tabs-anchor[text='Financial Modules']".click();`
- `findElement(By.cssSelector("li a.ui-tabs-anchor[text='Financial Modules']".click();`

It works fine for:

- `linktext= findElement(By.linkText("Financial Modules")).click();`
- `xpath=findElement(By.xpath("a[@class='ui-tabs-anchor'] [text()='Financial Modules']")).click();`

Comment: CSS Selectors can't reference the contained text, what's wrong with using the link text or XPath?

Comment: In this application, the text/Labels are unique, all the other ids are dynamic, hence for the consistency purpose i wanted to Locate them using cssSelector.

Comment: I would suggest that you use what you can to get the job done. In some cases you might be able to locate an element by linktext, in other cases you might have you use XPath to get text inside the element. I wouldn't worry about having all your locators be CSS selectors or whatever... that's not likely to be possible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** access innerHTML text using cssSelector this way, if you have such scenarios where you have to check text use xpath (or linkText if you are interacting with links) instead.